# Ubuntu alternative log in to GDM/Gnome or simplify gdm

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, kiosk

I want to remove to option for users to log in using gnome on Ubuntu 9.10 or preferably force their account to only log in using blackbox.

so for this there are 3 ways i've found to go at this

```
remove gnome and any other session type besided blackbox  
(gnome, gnome failsafe, and xsfd or somthing short like that)
```

then just install gnome when needed or just use blackbox

```
use a differnet log in system(text maybe)
```

i dont care for the ubuntu log in for this.  but ubuntu did something different for 9.10 so some things don't work

```
(preferably) some how force kiosk users to log in using blackbox but allow admin to log in using gnome maybe using command line.
```

is there a way have a text log in that still has the ability to auto login at start up?

the reasoning for this is blackbox has been set up for a kiosk with only a browser running, but gnome is mostly left alone for easy admin use.  Also kiosk users are auto logged in but its possable to disrupt the autologin and switch to gnome which i don't want.
also disableing the accesablity features would be nice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 9.10 removed the package for it (its on 9.04 and 10.04 though, wierdly enough) but slim would do the trick - i use the package off lucid on karmic, and it works fine, however. You can set slim to automatically log on to a particular account - iby editing /etc/slim.conf iirc . You'd then probably want to make sure users can't get to a VT, or log out somehow.